# .htaccess rewriting doesn't work in my PHP Code

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to rewrite the URL like this `127.0.0.1/profile.php?user=userName` to `127.0.0.1/user/userName` or `127.0.0.1/profile/userName`. it doesnt matter, but please please help me.

PHP Code:

```
<?php

require_once 'core/init.php';

if(!$username = Input::get('user')) {
    Redirect::to('index.php');
} else {
    $user = new User($username);

    if(!$user->exists()) {
        Redirect::to(404);
    } else {
        $data = $user->data();
?>

        <h3><?php echo escape($data->username); ?></h3>
        <p>Name: <?php echo escape($data->name); ?></p>

<?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running nginx or apache?

Comment: Please add your code, don't add an image, it doesn't help

Comment: I'm using Apache on Xampp.

Comment: @Sam Swift
<?php

require_once 'core/init.php';

if(!$username = Input::get('user')) {
    Redirect::to('index.php');
} else {
    $user = new User($username);

    if(!$user->exists()) {
        Redirect::to(404);
    } else {
        $data = $user->data();
?>

        <h3><?php echo escape($data->username); ?></h3>
        <p>Name: <?php echo escape($data->name); ?></p>

<?php
    }
}

Comment: @RedouanAzizim, in the question with the formatting is what I meant, indent every line of code by 4 spaces and add it to the question, much more readable :)

Comment: I'm so sorry, but i don't understand how i put the Code in..

Comment: @RedouanAzizim - there's an 'edit' button at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @RedouanAzizim, I have formatted your code for you. The trick is to copy it into your question (e.g. by using the **edit** link at the bottom-left of the question), then select it all and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button.

Comment: @RedouanAzizim, if the problem is with your `.htaccess, why don't you include that? The PHP code is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(user)/(\w+)/?$ profile.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```